# Problems updating cabal-install v. 1.20.0.3

Tags: haskell, cabal-install

**Problems updating cabal-install  v. 1.20.0.3**

The following is what I made

```
C:\Windows\system32>cabal update
```

Downloading the latest package list from hackage.haskell.org
Note: there is a new version of cabal-install available.
To upgrade, run: cabal install cabal-install

```
C:\Windows\system32>cabal install cabal-install
```

Resolving dependencies...
Configuring network-2.6.0.2...
cabal: The package has a './configure' script. **This requires a Unix
compatibility toolchain such as MinGW+MSYS or Cygwin.**
Failed to install network-2.6.0.2
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
HTTP-4000.2.19 depends on network-2.6.0.2 which failed to install.
cabal-install-1.20.0.4 depends on network-2.6.0.2 which failed to install.
network-2.6.0.2 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
**ExitFailure 1**

```
C:\Windows\system32>cabal --v
```

cabal-install version 1.20.0.3
using version 1.20.0.2 of the Cabal library

After these messages **I installed Cygwin64** and tried to reinstall "cabal-install", **but nothing changed**.

What can I do now? Thank you for your help.

CABAL INFO NETWORK

```
$ cabal info network
* network          (library)
    Synopsis:      Low-level networking interface
    Versions available: 2.3.2.0, 2.4.1.2, 2.4.2.1, 2.4.2.2, 2.4.2.3, 2.5.0.0,
                        2.6.0.0, 2.6.0.1, 2.6.0.2 (and 39 others)
    Versions installed: 2.4.2.3, 2.6.0.2
    Homepage:      https://github.com/haskell/network
    Bug reports:   https://github.com/haskell/network/issues
    Description:   This package provides a low-level networking interface.

                   In network-2.6 the @Network.URI@ module was split off into
                   its own package, network-uri-2.6. If you're using the
                   @Network.URI@ module you can automatically get it from the
                   right package by adding this to your .cabal file:

                   > flag network-uri > description: Get Network.URI from the
                   network-uri package > default: True > > library > -- ... > if
                   flag(network-uri) > build-depends: network-uri >= 2.6,
                   network >= 2.6 > else > build-depends: network-uri < 2.6,
                   network < 2.6

                   That is, get the module from either network < 2.6 or from
                   network-uri >= 2.6.
    Category:      Network
    License:       BSD3
    Maintainer:    Johan Tibell <johan.tibell@gmail.com>
    Source repo:   git://github.com/haskell/network.git
    Dependencies:  base >=3 && <5, bytestring <0.11, unix >=2,
                   test-framework-hunit -any, test-framework -any, network -any,
                   HUnit -any, bytestring -any, base <5,
                   test-framework-hunit -any, test-framework -any, network -any,
                   HUnit -any, bytestring -any, base <5
    Documentation: [ Not installed ]
    Cached:        Yes
    Modules:
        Network
        Network.BSD
        Network.Socket
        Network.Socket.ByteString
        Network.Socket.ByteString.Lazy
        Network.Socket.Internal
```

Following the latest instructions i tried:
I tried:

```
C:\Windows\system32>cabal install cabal-install --constraint="network==2.4.2.3"

...
Linking dist\build\cabal\cabal.exe ...
Installing executable(s) in C:\Users\Alberto\AppData\Roaming\cabal\bin
Installed cabal-install-1.20.0.4

C:\Windows\system32>cabal --v
cabal-install version 1.20.0.4
using version 1.20.0.2 of the Cabal library
```

Instead with: cabal install cabal-install -v --constraint="network==2.6.0.2"

These are the last lines:

```
c:/program files/haskell platform/2014.2.0.0/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-min
gw32/4.6.3/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: final link failed: Invalid
 operation
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Failed to install cabal-install-1.20.0.4
World file is already up to date.
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
cabal-install-1.20.0.4 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

The following is the incomplete version of the verbose process. (Incomplete because the Command Prompt window is too little to contain all the lines.) And also the "Body" of this post is "limited to 30000 characters" and I entered 43408.

```
Linking...
C:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\2014.2.0.0\bin\ghc.exe --make -fbuilding-cabal
-package -O -static -outputdir dist\build\cabal\cabal-tmp -odir dist\build\cabal
\cabal-tmp -hidir dist\build\cabal\cabal-tmp -stubdir dist\build\cabal\cabal-tmp
 -i -idist\build\cabal\cabal-tmp -i. -idist\build\autogen -Idist\build\autogen -
Idist\build\cabal\cabal-tmp -optP-DWIN32 -optP-include -optPdist\build\autogen\c
abal_macros.h -hide-all-packages -package-db dist\package.conf.inplace -package-
id Cabal-1.20.0.2-2d0d4b50a80873bd77d7619acdc39282 -package-id HTTP-4000.2.19-a3
b06338bfc05de6b2dff745ab78e8e2 -package-id Win32-2.3.0.2-698249828064ce7d3e73140
6aa0b6536 -package-id array-0.5.0.0-a620a6e52b09b01c2ee52fdc2f35ba14 -package-id
 base-4.7.0.1-7c4827d45272c6220486aa798a981cbc -package-id bytestring-0.10.4.0-0
168d7fce99b3d6589c7684c734053d4 -package-id containers-0.5.5.1-08015588ba3fe884f
62b392b72b7a17f -package-id directory-1.2.1.0-8cccd8e1806d43153b63c8c02500965e -
package-id filepath-1.3.0.2-a4d1d9ee29199e7f421cb1e2eeca7b3c -package-id mtl-2.1
.3.1-045b529925f92141fbca5a09ccb76887 -package-id network-2.6.0.2-cd717cc95784d3
d2c843373d48659787 -package-id network-uri-2.6.0.1-474d71b66fbfc5e5890f880a23bc7
62f -package-id pretty-1.1.1.1-c695907dd1419865c9783baf249b36b0 -package-id proc
ess-1.2.0.0-8428b2db1fb32008b84b305e3dcf61f8 -package-id random-1.0.1.1-1c39aaa7
8f370b133a79ccf1ef25922b -package-id stm-2.4.2-6e8cfbcce8457ecf64e4555b5e253ae6
-package-id time-1.4.2-10261674b91c0791587926806ccad1bb -package-id zlib-0.5.4.1
-28702d80c2a2842f8db883ae46443522 -XHaskell98 .\Main.hs dist\build\cabal\cabal-t
mp\cbits/getnumcores.o -o dist\build\cabal\cabal.exe -Wall -fwarn-tabs -threaded

Linking dist\build\cabal\cabal.exe ...
C:\Users\Alberto\AppData\Roaming\cabal\x86_64-windows-ghc-7.8.3\HTTP-4000.2.19/l
ibHSHTTP-4000.2.19.a(TCP.o):fake:(.text+0x26a6): undefined reference to `shutdow
nWinSock'
C:\Users\Alberto\AppData\Roaming\cabal\x86_64-windows-ghc-7.8.3\HTTP-4000.2.19/l
ibHSHTTP-4000.2.19.a(TCP.o):fake:(.text+0x2fae): undefined reference to `shutdow
nWinSock'
C:\Users\Alberto\AppData\Roaming\cabal\x86_64-windows-ghc-7.8.3\HTTP-4000.2.19/l
ibHSHTTP-4000.2.19.a(TCP.o):fake:(.text+0x300b): undefined reference to `initWin
Sock'
C:\Users\Alberto\AppData\Roaming\cabal\x86_64-windows-ghc-7.8.3\HTTP-4000.2.19/l
ibHSHTTP-4000.2.19.a(TCP.o):fake:(.text+0x3156): undefined reference to `shutdow
nWinSock'
C:\Users\Alberto\AppData\Roaming\cabal\x86_64-windows-ghc-7.8.3\HTTP-4000.2.19/l
ibHSHTTP-4000.2.19.a(TCP.o):fake:(.text+0x393e): undefined reference to `shutdow
nWinSock'
C:\Users\Alberto\AppData\Roaming\cabal\x86_64-windows-ghc-7.8.3\HTTP-4000.2.19/l
ibHSHTTP-4000.2.19.a(TCP.o):fake:(.text+0x399b): undefined reference to `initWin
Sock'
C:\Users\Alberto\AppData\Roaming\cabal\x86_64-windows-ghc-7.8.3\HTTP-4000.2.19/l
ibHSHTTP-4000.2.19.a(TCP.o):fake:(.text+0x3ade): undefined reference to `shutdow
nWinSock'
C:\Users\Alberto\AppData\Roaming\cabal\x86_64-windows-ghc-7.8.3\HTTP-4000.2.19/l
ibHSHTTP-4000.2.19.a(TCP.o):fake:(.text+0x4336): undefined reference to `shutdow
nWinSock'
C:\Users\Alberto\AppData\Roaming\cabal\x86_64-windows-ghc-7.8.3\HTTP-4000.2.19/l
ibHSHTTP-4000.2.19.a(TCP.o):fake:(.text+0x4393): undefined reference to `initWin
Sock'
C:\Users\Alberto\AppData\Roaming\cabal\x86_64-windows-ghc-7.8.3\HTTP-4000.2.19/l
ibHSHTTP-4000.2.19.a(TCP.o):fake:(.text+0x44d6): undefined reference to `shutdow
nWinSock'
C:\Users\Alberto\AppData\Roaming\cabal\x86_64-windows-ghc-7.8.3\HTTP-4000.2.19/l
ibHSHTTP-4000.2.19.a(TCP.o):fake:(.text+0x4c8e): undefined reference to `shutdow
nWinSock'
C:\Users\Alberto\AppData\Roaming\cabal\x86_64-windows-ghc-7.8.3\HTTP-4000.2.19/l
ibHSHTTP-4000.2.19.a(TCP.o):fake:(.text+0x4ceb): undefined reference to `initWin
Sock'
C:\Users\Alberto\AppData\Roaming\cabal\x86_64-windows-ghc-7.8.3\HTTP-4000.2.19/l
ibHSHTTP-4000.2.19.a(TCP.o):fake:(.text+0x4e36): undefined reference to `shutdow
nWinSock'
c:/program files/haskell platform/2014.2.0.0/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-min
gw32/4.6.3/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Alberto\AppData\R
oaming\cabal\x86_64-windows-ghc-7.8.3\HTTP-4000.2.19/libHSHTTP-4000.2.19.a(TCP.o
): bad reloc address 0x0 in section `.data'
c:/program files/haskell platform/2014.2.0.0/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-min
gw32/4.6.3/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: final link failed: Invalid
 operation
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Failed to install cabal-install-1.20.0.4
World file is already up to date.
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
cabal-install-1.20.0.4 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1

cabal install cabal-install -v --constraint="network==2.6.0.2"


[17 of 76] Compiling Distribution.Client.Types ( Distribution\Client\Types.hs, d
ist\build\cabal\cabal-tmp\Distribution\Client\Types.o )
[18 of 76] Compiling Distribution.Client.Dependency.Modular.Flag ( Distribution\
Client\Dependency\Modular\Flag.hs, dist\build\cabal\cabal-tmp\Distribution\Clien
t\Dependency\Modular\Flag.o )
[19 of 76] Compiling Distribution.Client.Dependency.Modular.Dependency ( Distrib
ution\Client\Dependency\Modular\Dependency.hs, dist\build\cabal\cabal-tmp\Distri
bution\Client\Dependency\Modular\Dependency.o )
[20 of 76] Compiling Distribution.Client.Dependency.Modular.Tree ( Distribution\
Client\Dependency\Modular\Tree.hs, dist\build\cabal\cabal-tmp\Distribution\Clien
t\Dependency\Modular\Tree.o )
[21 of 76] Compiling Distribution.Client.Dependency.Modular.Index ( Distribution
\Client\Dependency\Modular\Index.hs, dist\build\cabal\cabal-tmp\Distribution\Cli
ent\Dependency\Modular\Index.o )
[22 of 76] Compiling Distribution.Client.Dependency.Modular.Builder ( Distributi
on\Client\Dependency\Modular\Builder.hs, dist\build\cabal\cabal-tmp\Distribution
\Client\Dependency\Modular\Builder.o )
[23 of 76] Compiling Distribution.Client.Dependency.Modular.Message ( Distributi
on\Client\Dependency\Modular\Message.hs, dist\build\cabal\cabal-tmp\Distribution
\Client\Dependency\Modular\Message.o )
[24 of 76] Compiling Distribution.Client.Dependency.Modular.Configured ( Distrib
ution\Client\Dependency\Modular\Configured.hs, dist\build\cabal\cabal-tmp\Distri
bution\Client\Dependency\Modular\Configured.o )
[25 of 76] Compiling Distribution.Client.Dependency.Modular.Assignment ( Distrib
ution\Client\Dependency\Modular\Assignment.hs, dist\build\cabal\cabal-tmp\Distri
bution\Client\Dependency\Modular\Assignment.o )
[26 of 76] Compiling Distribution.Client.Dependency.Modular.Validate ( Distribut
ion\Client\Dependency\Modular\Validate.hs, dist\build\cabal\cabal-tmp\Distributi
on\Client\Dependency\Modular\Validate.o )
[27 of 76] Compiling Distribution.Client.Dependency.TopDown.Types ( Distribution
\Client\Dependency\TopDown\Types.hs, dist\build\cabal\cabal-tmp\Distribution\Cli
ent\Dependency\TopDown\Types.o )
[28 of 76] Compiling Distribution.Client.Dependency.Modular.IndexConversion ( Di
stribution\Client\Dependency\Modular\IndexConversion.hs, dist\build\cabal\cabal-
tmp\Distribution\Client\Dependency\Modular\IndexConversion.o )
[29 of 76] Compiling Distribution.Client.Init.Licenses ( Distribution\Client\Ini
t\Licenses.hs, dist\build\cabal\cabal-tmp\Distribution\Client\Init\Licenses.o )
[30 of 76] Compiling Distribution.Client.Init.Types ( Distribution\Client\Init\T
ypes.hs, dist\build\cabal\cabal-tmp\Distribution\Client\Init\Types.o )
[31 of 76] Compiling Distribution.Client.Compat.Time ( Distribution\Client\Compa
t\Time.hs, dist\build\cabal\cabal-tmp\Distribution\Client\Compat\Time.o )

Distribution\Client\Compat\Time.hs:27:1: Warning:
    the 'stdcall' calling convention is unsupported on this platform,
    treating as ccall
    When checking declaration:
      foreign import stdcall safe "static windows.h GetFileAttributesExW" c_getF
ileAttributesEx
        :: LPCTSTR -> Int32 -> LPVOID -> IO BOOL

Distribution\Client\Compat\Time.hs:90:62: Warning:
    In the use of `bitSize' (imported from Data.Bits):
    Deprecated: "Use 'bitSizeMaybe' or 'finiteBitSize' instead"
[32 of 76] Compiling Distribution.Client.Tar ( Distribution\Client\Tar.hs, dist\
build\cabal\cabal-tmp\Distribution\Client\Tar.o )
[33 of 76] Compiling Paths_cabal_install ( dist\build\autogen\Paths_cabal_instal
l.hs, dist\build\cabal\cabal-tmp\Paths_cabal_install.o )
[34 of 76] Compiling Distribution.Client.HttpUtils ( Distribution\Client\HttpUti
ls.hs, dist\build\cabal\cabal-tmp\Distribution\Client\HttpUtils.o )
[35 of 76] Compiling Distribution.Client.FetchUtils ( Distribution\Client\FetchU
tils.hs, dist\build\cabal\cabal-tmp\Distribution\Client\FetchUtils.o )
[36 of 76] Compiling Distribution.Client.Utils ( Distribution\Client\Utils.hs, d
ist\build\cabal\cabal-tmp\Distribution\Client\Utils.o )
[37 of 76] Compiling Distribution.Client.Init.Heuristics ( Distribution\Client\I
nit\Heuristics.hs, dist\build\cabal\cabal-tmp\Distribution\Client\Init\Heuristic
s.o )
[38 of 76] Compiling Distribution.Client.IndexUtils ( Distribution\Client\IndexU
tils.hs, dist\build\cabal\cabal-tmp\Distribution\Client\IndexUtils.o )
[39 of 76] Compiling Distribution.Client.Sandbox.Index ( Distribution\Client\San
dbox\Index.hs, dist\build\cabal\cabal-tmp\Distribution\Client\Sandbox\Index.o )
[40 of 76] Compiling Distribution.Client.InstallPlan ( Distribution\Client\Insta
llPlan.hs, dist\build\cabal\cabal-tmp\Distribution\Client\InstallPlan.o )
[41 of 76] Compiling Distribution.Client.Dependency.Types ( Distribution\Client\
Dependency\Types.hs, dist\build\cabal\cabal-tmp\Distribution\Client\Dependency\T
ypes.o )
[42 of 76] Compiling Distribution.Client.Dependency.Modular.Log ( Distribution\C
lient\Dependency\Modular\Log.hs, dist\build\cabal\cabal-tmp\Distribution\Client\
Dependency\Modular\Log.o )
[43 of 76] Compiling Distribution.Client.Dependency.Modular.Explore ( Distributi
on\Client\Dependency\Modular\Explore.hs, dist\build\cabal\cabal-tmp\Distribution
\Client\Dependency\Modular\Explore.o )
[44 of 76] Compiling Distribution.Client.Dependency.Modular.Preference ( Distrib
ution\Client\Dependency\Modular\Preference.hs, dist\build\cabal\cabal-tmp\Distri
bution\Client\Dependency\Modular\Preference.o )
[45 of 76] Compiling Distribution.Client.Dependency.Modular.Solver ( Distributio
n\Client\Dependency\Modular\Solver.hs, dist\build\cabal\cabal-tmp\Distribution\C
lient\Dependency\Modular\Solver.o )
[46 of 76] Compiling Distribution.Client.Dependency.Modular.ConfiguredConversion
 ( Distribution\Client\Dependency\Modular\ConfiguredConversion.hs, dist\build\ca
bal\cabal-tmp\Distribution\Client\Dependency\Modular\ConfiguredConversion.o )
[47 of 76] Compiling Distribution.Client.Dependency.Modular ( Distribution\Clien
t\Dependency\Modular.hs, dist\build\cabal\cabal-tmp\Distribution\Client\Dependen
cy\Modular.o )
[48 of 76] Compiling Distribution.Client.BuildReports.Anonymous ( Distribution\C
lient\BuildReports\Anonymous.hs, dist\build\cabal\cabal-tmp\Distribution\Client\
BuildReports\Anonymous.o )
[49 of 76] Compiling Distribution.Client.BuildReports.Storage ( Distribution\Cli
ent\BuildReports\Storage.hs, dist\build\cabal\cabal-tmp\Distribution\Client\Buil
dReports\Storage.o )
[50 of 76] Compiling Distribution.Client.BuildReports.Upload ( Distribution\Clie
nt\BuildReports\Upload.hs, dist\build\cabal\cabal-tmp\Distribution\Client\BuildR
eports\Upload.o )
[51 of 76] Compiling Distribution.Client.Dependency.TopDown.Constraints ( Distri
bution\Client\Dependency\TopDown\Constraints.hs, dist\build\cabal\cabal-tmp\Dist
ribution\Client\Dependency\TopDown\Constraints.o )
[52 of 76] Compiling Distribution.Client.Dependency.TopDown ( Distribution\Clien
t\Dependency\TopDown.hs, dist\build\cabal\cabal-tmp\Distribution\Client\Dependen
cy\TopDown.o )
[53 of 76] Compiling Distribution.Client.Win32SelfUpgrade ( Distribution\Client\
Win32SelfUpgrade.hs, dist\build\cabal\cabal-tmp\Distribution\Client\Win32SelfUpg
rade.o )

Distribution\Client\Win32SelfUpgrade.hs:48:1: Warning:
    The qualified import of `System.Win32.DLL' is redundant
      except perhaps to import instances from `System.Win32.DLL'
    To import instances alone, use: import System.Win32.DLL()

Distribution\Client\Win32SelfUpgrade.hs:164:1: Warning:
    the 'stdcall' calling convention is unsupported on this platform,
    treating as ccall
    When checking declaration:
      foreign import stdcall unsafe "static windows.h GetCurrentProcessId" getCu
rrentProcessId
        :: IO DWORD

Distribution\Client\Win32SelfUpgrade.hs:167:1: Warning:
    the 'stdcall' calling convention is unsupported on this platform,
    treating as ccall
    When checking declaration:
      foreign import stdcall unsafe "static windows.h WaitForSingleObject" waitF
orSingleObject_
        :: HANDLE -> DWORD -> IO DWORD

Distribution\Client\Win32SelfUpgrade.hs:178:1: Warning:
    the 'stdcall' calling convention is unsupported on this platform,
    treating as ccall
    When checking declaration:
      foreign import stdcall unsafe "static windows.h CreateEventW" createEvent_

        :: Ptr () -> BOOL -> BOOL -> LPCTSTR -> IO HANDLE

Distribution\Client\Win32SelfUpgrade.hs:187:1: Warning:
    the 'stdcall' calling convention is unsupported on this platform,
    treating as ccall
    When checking declaration:
      foreign import stdcall unsafe "static windows.h OpenEventW" openEvent_
        :: DWORD -> BOOL -> LPCTSTR -> IO HANDLE

Distribution\Client\Win32SelfUpgrade.hs:199:1: Warning:
    the 'stdcall' calling convention is unsupported on this platform,
    treating as ccall
    When checking declaration:
      foreign import stdcall unsafe "static windows.h SetEvent" setEvent_
        :: HANDLE -> IO BOOL
[54 of 76] Compiling Distribution.Client.Init ( Distribution\Client\Init.hs, dis
t\build\cabal\cabal-tmp\Distribution\Client\Init.o )
[55 of 76] Compiling Distribution.Client.Sandbox.Types ( Distribution\Client\San
dbox\Types.hs, dist\build\cabal\cabal-tmp\Distribution\Client\Sandbox\Types.o )
[56 of 76] Compiling Distribution.Client.Run ( Distribution\Client\Run.hs, dist\
build\cabal\cabal-tmp\Distribution\Client\Run.o )
[57 of 76] Compiling Distribution.Client.Check ( Distribution\Client\Check.hs, d
ist\build\cabal\cabal-tmp\Distribution\Client\Check.o )
[58 of 76] Compiling Distribution.Client.Update ( Distribution\Client\Update.hs,
 dist\build\cabal\cabal-tmp\Distribution\Client\Update.o )
[59 of 76] Compiling Distribution.Client.Targets ( Distribution\Client\Targets.h
s, dist\build\cabal\cabal-tmp\Distribution\Client\Targets.o )
[60 of 76] Compiling Distribution.Client.Dependency ( Distribution\Client\Depend
ency.hs, dist\build\cabal\cabal-tmp\Distribution\Client\Dependency.o )
[61 of 76] Compiling Distribution.Client.Setup ( Distribution\Client\Setup.hs, d
ist\build\cabal\cabal-tmp\Distribution\Client\Setup.o )
[62 of 76] Compiling Distribution.Client.Config ( Distribution\Client\Config.hs,
 dist\build\cabal\cabal-tmp\Distribution\Client\Config.o )
[63 of 76] Compiling Distribution.Client.SetupWrapper ( Distribution\Client\Setu
pWrapper.hs, dist\build\cabal\cabal-tmp\Distribution\Client\SetupWrapper.o )
[64 of 76] Compiling Distribution.Client.Sandbox.Timestamp ( Distribution\Client
\Sandbox\Timestamp.hs, dist\build\cabal\cabal-tmp\Distribution\Client\Sandbox\Ti
mestamp.o )
[65 of 76] Compiling Distribution.Client.Upload ( Distribution\Client\Upload.hs,
 dist\build\cabal\cabal-tmp\Distribution\Client\Upload.o )
[66 of 76] Compiling Distribution.Client.List ( Distribution\Client\List.hs, dis
t\build\cabal\cabal-tmp\Distribution\Client\List.o )
[67 of 76] Compiling Distribution.Client.Configure ( Distribution\Client\Configu
re.hs, dist\build\cabal\cabal-tmp\Distribution\Client\Configure.o )
[68 of 76] Compiling Distribution.Client.Fetch ( Distribution\Client\Fetch.hs, d
ist\build\cabal\cabal-tmp\Distribution\Client\Fetch.o )
[69 of 76] Compiling Distribution.Client.SrcDist ( Distribution\Client\SrcDist.h
s, dist\build\cabal\cabal-tmp\Distribution\Client\SrcDist.o )
[70 of 76] Compiling Distribution.Client.Get ( Distribution\Client\Get.hs, dist\
build\cabal\cabal-tmp\Distribution\Client\Get.o )
[71 of 76] Compiling Distribution.Client.Sandbox.PackageEnvironment ( Distributi
on\Client\Sandbox\PackageEnvironment.hs, dist\build\cabal\cabal-tmp\Distribution
\Client\Sandbox\PackageEnvironment.o )
[72 of 76] Compiling Distribution.Client.Freeze ( Distribution\Client\Freeze.hs,
 dist\build\cabal\cabal-tmp\Distribution\Client\Freeze.o )
[73 of 76] Compiling Distribution.Client.InstallSymlink ( Distribution\Client\In
stallSymlink.hs, dist\build\cabal\cabal-tmp\Distribution\Client\InstallSymlink.o
 )
[74 of 76] Compiling Distribution.Client.Install ( Distribution\Client\Install.h
s, dist\build\cabal\cabal-tmp\Distribution\Client\Install.o )
[75 of 76] Compiling Distribution.Client.Sandbox ( Distribution\Client\Sandbox.h
s, dist\build\cabal\cabal-tmp\Distribution\Client\Sandbox.o )
[76 of 76] Compiling Main             ( Main.hs, dist\build\cabal\cabal-tmp\Main
.o )
Building C Sources...
creating dist\build\cabal\cabal-tmp
C:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\2014.2.0.0\bin\ghc.exe -c -static -odir dist\b
uild\cabal\cabal-tmp -Idist\build\autogen -Idist\build\cabal\cabal-tmp -optc-O2
-package-db dist\package.conf.inplace -package-id Cabal-1.20.0.2-2d0d4b50a80873b
d77d7619acdc39282 -package-id HTTP-4000.2.19-a3b06338bfc05de6b2dff745ab78e8e2 -p
ackage-id Win32-2.3.0.2-698249828064ce7d3e731406aa0b6536 -package-id array-0.5.0
.0-a620a6e52b09b01c2ee52fdc2f35ba14 -package-id base-4.7.0.1-7c4827d45272c622048
6aa798a981cbc -package-id bytestring-0.10.4.0-0168d7fce99b3d6589c7684c734053d4 -
package-id containers-0.5.5.1-08015588ba3fe884f62b392b72b7a17f -package-id direc
tory-1.2.1.0-8cccd8e1806d43153b63c8c02500965e -package-id filepath-1.3.0.2-a4d1d
9ee29199e7f421cb1e2eeca7b3c -package-id mtl-2.1.3.1-045b529925f92141fbca5a09ccb7
6887 -package-id network-2.6.0.2-cd717cc95784d3d2c843373d48659787 -package-id ne
twork-uri-2.6.0.1-474d71b66fbfc5e5890f880a23bc762f -package-id pretty-1.1.1.1-c6
95907dd1419865c9783baf249b36b0 -package-id process-1.2.0.0-8428b2db1fb32008b84b3
05e3dcf61f8 -package-id random-1.0.1.1-1c39aaa78f370b133a79ccf1ef25922b -package
-id stm-2.4.2-6e8cfbcce8457ecf64e4555b5e253ae6 -package-id time-1.4.2-10261674b9
1c0791587926806ccad1bb -package-id zlib-0.5.4.1-28702d80c2a2842f8db883ae46443522
 cbits/getnumcores.c
Linking...
C:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\2014.2.0.0\bin\ghc.exe --make -fbuilding-cabal
-package -O -static -outputdir dist\build\cabal\cabal-tmp -odir dist\build\cabal
\cabal-tmp -hidir dist\build\cabal\cabal-tmp -stubdir dist\build\cabal\cabal-tmp
 -i -idist\build\cabal\cabal-tmp -i. -idist\build\autogen -Idist\build\autogen -
Idist\build\cabal\cabal-tmp -optP-DWIN32 -optP-include -optPdist\build\autogen\c
abal_macros.h -hide-all-packages -package-db dist\package.conf.inplace -package-
id Cabal-1.20.0.2-2d0d4b50a80873bd77d7619acdc39282 -package-id HTTP-4000.2.19-a3
b06338bfc05de6b2dff745ab78e8e2 -package-id Win32-2.3.0.2-698249828064ce7d3e73140
6aa0b6536 -package-id array-0.5.0.0-a620a6e52b09b01c2ee52fdc2f35ba14 -package-id
 base-4.7.0.1-7c4827d45272c6220486aa798a981cbc -package-id bytestring-0.10.4.0-0
168d7fce99b3d6589c7684c734053d4 -package-id containers-0.5.5.1-08015588ba3fe884f
62b392b72b7a17f -package-id directory-1.2.1.0-8cccd8e1806d43153b63c8c02500965e -
package-id filepath-1.3.0.2-a4d1d9ee29199e7f421cb1e2eeca7b3c -package-id mtl-2.1
.3.1-045b529925f92141fbca5a09ccb76887 -package-id network-2.6.0.2-cd717cc95784d3
d2c843373d48659787 -package-id network-uri-2.6.0.1-474d71b66fbfc5e5890f880a23bc7
62f -package-id pretty-1.1.1.1-c695907dd1419865c9783baf249b36b0 -package-id proc
ess-1.2.0.0-8428b2db1fb32008b84b305e3dcf61f8 -package-id random-1.0.1.1-1c39aaa7
8f370b133a79ccf1ef25922b -package-id stm-2.4.2-6e8cfbcce8457ecf64e4555b5e253ae6
-package-id time-1.4.2-10261674b91c0791587926806ccad1bb -package-id zlib-0.5.4.1
-28702d80c2a2842f8db883ae46443522 -XHaskell98 .\Main.hs dist\build\cabal\cabal-t
mp\cbits/getnumcores.o -o dist\build\cabal\cabal.exe -Wall -fwarn-tabs -threaded

Linking dist\build\cabal\cabal.exe ...
C:\Users\Alberto\AppData\Roaming\cabal\x86_64-windows-ghc-7.8.3\HTTP-4000.2.19/l
ibHSHTTP-4000.2.19.a(TCP.o):fake:(.text+0x26a6): undefined reference to `shutdow
nWinSock'
C:\Users\Alberto\AppData\Roaming\cabal\x86_64-windows-ghc-7.8.3\HTTP-4000.2.19/l
ibHSHTTP-4000.2.19.a(TCP.o):fake:(.text+0x2fae): undefined reference to `shutdow
nWinSock'
C:\Users\Alberto\AppData\Roaming\cabal\x86_64-windows-ghc-7.8.3\HTTP-4000.2.19/l
ibHSHTTP-4000.2.19.a(TCP.o):fake:(.text+0x300b): undefined reference to `initWin
Sock'
C:\Users\Alberto\AppData\Roaming\cabal\x86_64-windows-ghc-7.8.3\HTTP-4000.2.19/l
ibHSHTTP-4000.2.19.a(TCP.o):fake:(.text+0x3156): undefined reference to `shutdow
nWinSock'
C:\Users\Alberto\AppData\Roaming\cabal\x86_64-windows-ghc-7.8.3\HTTP-4000.2.19/l
ibHSHTTP-4000.2.19.a(TCP.o):fake:(.text+0x393e): undefined reference to `shutdow
nWinSock'
C:\Users\Alberto\AppData\Roaming\cabal\x86_64-windows-ghc-7.8.3\HTTP-4000.2.19/l
ibHSHTTP-4000.2.19.a(TCP.o):fake:(.text+0x399b): undefined reference to `initWin
Sock'
C:\Users\Alberto\AppData\Roaming\cabal\x86_64-windows-ghc-7.8.3\HTTP-4000.2.19/l
ibHSHTTP-4000.2.19.a(TCP.o):fake:(.text+0x3ade): undefined reference to `shutdow
nWinSock'
C:\Users\Alberto\AppData\Roaming\cabal\x86_64-windows-ghc-7.8.3\HTTP-4000.2.19/l
ibHSHTTP-4000.2.19.a(TCP.o):fake:(.text+0x4336): undefined reference to `shutdow
nWinSock'
C:\Users\Alberto\AppData\Roaming\cabal\x86_64-windows-ghc-7.8.3\HTTP-4000.2.19/l
ibHSHTTP-4000.2.19.a(TCP.o):fake:(.text+0x4393): undefined reference to `initWin
Sock'
C:\Users\Alberto\AppData\Roaming\cabal\x86_64-windows-ghc-7.8.3\HTTP-4000.2.19/l
ibHSHTTP-4000.2.19.a(TCP.o):fake:(.text+0x44d6): undefined reference to `shutdow
nWinSock'
C:\Users\Alberto\AppData\Roaming\cabal\x86_64-windows-ghc-7.8.3\HTTP-4000.2.19/l
ibHSHTTP-4000.2.19.a(TCP.o):fake:(.text+0x4c8e): undefined reference to `shutdow
nWinSock'
C:\Users\Alberto\AppData\Roaming\cabal\x86_64-windows-ghc-7.8.3\HTTP-4000.2.19/l
ibHSHTTP-4000.2.19.a(TCP.o):fake:(.text+0x4ceb): undefined reference to `initWin
Sock'
C:\Users\Alberto\AppData\Roaming\cabal\x86_64-windows-ghc-7.8.3\HTTP-4000.2.19/l
ibHSHTTP-4000.2.19.a(TCP.o):fake:(.text+0x4e36): undefined reference to `shutdow
nWinSock'
c:/program files/haskell platform/2014.2.0.0/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-min
gw32/4.6.3/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Alberto\AppData\R
oaming\cabal\x86_64-windows-ghc-7.8.3\HTTP-4000.2.19/libHSHTTP-4000.2.19.a(TCP.o
): bad reloc address 0x0 in section `.data'
c:/program files/haskell platform/2014.2.0.0/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-min
gw32/4.6.3/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: final link failed: Invalid
 operation
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Failed to install cabal-install-1.20.0.4
World file is already up to date.
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
cabal-install-1.20.0.4 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

Comment: You've installed both cabal and ghc via Haskell Platform?

Comment: Yes, I installed Haskell Platform 2014.2

Comment: The Cygwin versioni is: GNU bash, version 4.1.17(9)-release (x86_64-unknown-cygwin)

Comment: Did you run Cabal in Command Prompt or in Cygwin's Bash shell?  What version(s) of `network` do you currently have installed?  (Run `cabal info network` to find out.)

Comment: You shouldn't need to reinstall network to install cabal-install. And it shouldn't matter anyways - you have v1.20.0.3 and are updating to v1.20.0.4. This is a very tiny version difference not worth updating over. You certainly won't be missing any features. But 1.20.0.4 seems to have too tight dependencies, which is the reason for the error you see.

Comment: Or try `cabal install cabal-install --constraint="network==x.y.z.w"`, where x.y.z.w is *your* version of network.

Comment: @Rufflewind: i tried to cabal-install in Cygwin's Bash shell, but these are the last lines: 

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Failed to install cabal-install-1.20.0.4

cabal.exe: Error: some packages failed to install:

cabal-install-1.20.0.4 failed during the building phase. The exception was:

ExitFailure 1

Alberto@Alberto-PC ~
$ cabal --v

cabal-install version 1.20.0.3

using version 1.20.0.2 of the Cabal library

Comment: @user2407038:
1) have I to write the new command in Cygwin's Bash shell?

2) I think that " network-2.6.0.2 which failed to install" is not the correct network. How can obtain the current network version?

Thank you.

Comment: Run `cabal info network` to find out what your current version of `network` is.  Also, if you have detailed error messages, edit them into your question.

Comment: @Rufflewind: I added the network information in the main post.

Comment: @AlbertoCapitani Pick either of the versions of `network` that you already have installed and then add the `--constraint` flag that user2407038 mentioned, then let us know if it worked or still causes problems.  Be sure to install with the `-v` (verbose) flag so you can see all the error messages.

Comment: @Rufflewind  network: Versions installed: 2.4.2.3, 2.6.0.2
in Cygwin: collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Failed to install cabal-install-1.22.0.1
cabal.exe: Error: some packages failed to install:
cabal-install-1.22.0.1 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1

in Command Prompt:
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Failed to install cabal-install-1.22.0.1
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
cabal-install-1.22.0.1 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1